# AngularJS ng-repeat - repeat childs only

Tags: angularjs

I try display in loop data but without repeating div with ng-repeat.

Example:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in widget"  ng-include="includeFile(item.type)"></div>
```

Output:

```
<div class="ng-scope" ng-include="includeFile(item.type)" ng-repeat="item in widget">
data from template
</div>
<div class="ng-scope" ng-include="includeFile(item.type)" ng-repeat="item in widget">
data from template
</div>
```

I want output data in one div:

```
<div>
    data from template
    data from template
</div>
```

How can I do this in Angular?

Comment: You wouldn't - you would wrap your content in a container and repeat on that - how would you perform any actions on the repeated items? Put them in a `span` within your div (or any other kind of container element)

Comment: OK but I have above container and elements from templates are draggable etc in this container. When Angular add to all iteration div with ng-repeat elements are draggable in this div's, bo main container...

Comment: I have the same question, and for me it is because I am using tables. I want to have multiple TR inside my ng-repeat, but I can't put the ng-repeat on the tbody...

Comment: @Zwik you want to repeat `<tr>` not `<tbody>` .

Comment: exaclty, but I cant have multiple TR in the same ng-repeat then...